# Compile time encryption for strings using user-defined literals

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, c++14, user-defined-literals

I am aware that the new C++ standard allows for user-defined literals and that their generation can be done in compile time.

However, I am quite new to the whole template metaprogramming universe and I'm trying to get some examples going, but still without success, since it's the first time I have contact with this particular feature.

So let's say I have a string:

```
std::string tmp = "This is a test message";
```

And I would like to encrypt it at compile time using:

```
std::string tmp = "This is a test message"_encrypt;
```

Is it even possible what I'm trying to attempt?

I am currently using VS2015 so any help or feedback is appreciated.

Comment: `std::string` is not a literal type, so you can't use `constexpr` with it. The 'encryption' won't happen compile-time, but rather at program start.

Comment: @sp2danny, what if I would use `const char*` instead?

Comment: Well, if encrypt returned a constexpr string type like a string_view i think it should work.  You might have to still cast to a std::string though.  `std::experimental::string_view operator""_encrypt(const char *);` or `std::experimental::string_view operator""_encrypt(const char *, size_t);`.  I can't remember if string_view has a str() member or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it even possible what I'm trying to attempt?

Yes, it is possible<sub>*</sub>. What *you* can pre-compute and put directly in the source code can also be done by the compiler at compile time.

However, you cannot use `std::string`. It's not a literal type. Something like:

```
 constexpr std::string tmp = "some string literal"
```

will *never* compile because `std::string` and `std::basic_string` in general have no `constexpr` constructor.

You must therefore use `const char []` as input for your meta-programming; after that, you may assign it to a `std::string`.
NB: Meta-programming has some restrictions you need to take into account: you don't have access to many tools you'd otherwise have, like `new` or `malloc`, for example: you must allocate on the stack your variables.

---

**<sub>*</sub>Edit:** Not entirely with UDLs, as @m.s. points out. Indeed, you receive a pointer to `const char`s and the length of the string. This is pretty restrictive in a `constexpr` scenario, and I doubt it's possible to find a way to work on that string. In "normal" meta-programming, where you can have a size that is a constant expression, compile-time encryption is instead possible.

Comment: how would you manipulate the char array in a constexpr function?

Comment: but you can't allocate memory in a `constexpr` function, I am really curious how that would work

Comment: @m.s. You can't allocate dynamic memory, but you can use automatic arrays.

Comment: what is an automatic array?

Comment: @m.s I meant an array with automatic storage duration. Like `char s[N]`.

Comment: but you don't get the size of the character array as a compile time constant

Comment: @m.s What do you mean? Just `template <size_t N> constexpr auto(const char (&s)[N]) `, where `N` is the length.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84814/discussion-between-m-s-and-black).